# Что делают указатели в приведенном методе?

Tags: c#, .net

Пример:

```
// Copies count bytes from src to dst. The source and destination
// blocks are permitted to overlap.
public static void Copy(void* src, void* dst, int count)
{
    byte* ps = (byte*)src;
    byte* pd = (byte*)dst;
    if (ps > pd)
    {
        for (; count != 0; count--) 
            *pd++ = *ps++; // Тут
    }
    else if (ps < pd)
    {
        for (ps += count, pd += count; count != 0; count--)
            *--pd = *--ps; // И тут
    }
}
```

Для меня понятно что именно делает данный метод. Для меня непонятно шаманство с указателями. Почему например в else if используется префикс, а в if постфикс? Можете разъяснить подробно?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Все дело в инварианте цикла.

Когда идет побайтовое копирование "вперед" - указатели указывают на первый байт еще не обработанной области памяти:

```
----dddddddd----          ----ssssssss----
    ^                         ^
    |                         |
    pd                        ps
```

Поэтому, на каждом шаге цикла происходит сначала копирование - потом сдвиг указателей:

```
*pd = *ps;
pd = pd + 1;
ps = ps + 1;
```

Запись `*pd++ = *ps++` является более коротким способом записать три строчки выше. Используемая тут операция - постинкремент - увеличивает переменную, возвращая при этом *старое* значение переменной.

При копировании в обратную сторону - так получается, что указатель указывает на байт, идущий сразу после необработанного блока памяти:

```
----ssssssss----          ----dddddddd----
            ^                         ^
            |                         |
            ps                        pd
```

Поэтому, на каждой итерации цикла его сначала сдвигают - а потом уже делают присваивание:

```
ps = ps - 1;
pd = pd - 1;
*pd = *ps;
```

Более коротко это записывается как `*--pd = *--ps`. используемая операция - предекремент - уменьшает переменную, возвращая *новое* значение переменной.

Comment: Это код внутренней реализации memmove в .NET, насколько я понимаю.

Comment: Этот ответ должен быть принят, т.к. только он отвечает на вопрос.

Comment: @VladD не посмотрел на тэги :)

Comment: @All, тут кто то проминусовал ответы, сразу оговорюсь - что это был не я.

Comment: Отлично, а я как обычно не так вопрос понял) и начал думать для чего там сравнивают указатели :-)

Answer (score 2):

```
// Copies count bytes from src to dst. The source and destination
// blocks are permitted to overlap.
public static void Copy(void* src, void* dst, int count)
{
    byte* ps = (byte*)src; //Приводим указатель к типу byte
    byte* pd = (byte*)dst; //Приводим указатель к типу byte
    if (ps > pd)
    {
        for (; count != 0; count--) 
            *pd++ = *ps++; // Присваиваем текущему блоку (1 байт) в pd 
                           // Значение из ps, и сдвигаемся после этого 
                           //на 1 байт вправо (и pd и ps)
    }
    else if (ps < pd)
    {
        for (ps += count, pd += count; count != 0; count--)
            *--pd = *--ps; // Сдвигаемся на 1 байт влево (и pd и ps)
                           // и присваиваем текущему блоку (1 байт) в pd 
                           // Значение из ps
    }
}
```

**постинкремент** (**постфикс** по Вашему) - сначала выполняется операция, потом инкремент
**предекремент** (**префикс** по Вашему) - сначала декримент, потом операция.

Но почему именно так сделано, сразу сложно сказать, думаю нужно более подробно изучить код в целом.

**P.S.** Надеюсь правильно понял, т.к. в C# с указателями я не работал, только в C++

Comment: потому что позицию указателя в памяти меняют, поэтому и сдвигают туда-сюда

Comment: @All, плохо что нельзя оба вопроса отметить как правильные, и приходится выбирать. Всем спасибо, теперь понятная логика.

Comment: @Senior Automator спасибо кэп :-) то что там сдвигают туда-сюда это итак понятно :-) я имел ввиду что непонятно для чего сравнивают позиции указателей, и на основе этого потом решают копировать вправо или влево, я так понял копирование идет в пределах одного блока данных.

Answer (score 2):

этот метод копирует определенное число(`count`) байтов из исходного буфера(`src`) в буфер назначения(`dst`).

> *pd++ = *ps++; // Тут
>   присваивает по 1 байту и сдвигает вправо
>
> *--pd = *--ps; // И тут
>   сдвиг влево по байту